# How to build several targets by invoking only one command?

Tags: makefile

I got a Makefile like the following:

```
.PHONY: all

all: aaa.2 bbb.2

aaa.2 : aaa.1 common.1
    create_2 $@

bbb.2 : bbb.1 common.1
    create_2 $@
```

The program create_2 takes long time to start, but is able to create several %.2 files at once, therefore I would like to invoke create_2 only once.

For example if common.1 has changed, I would like `create_2 aaa.2 bbb.2` to be invoked instead of both `create_2 aaa.2` and `create_2 bbb.2`.

I tried with a `create_2 $?` recipe in the 'all' target, but without success.

I'm searching for a solution that is working with both gmake and clearmake (in gnu compatibility mode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make is basically file-oriented, and what you want is something process-oriented, so... maybe that excuses the fact that this is a horrible kludge:

```
.PHONY: all

all: marker

aaa.2 : aaa.1 common.1
    @touch $@

bbb.2 : bbb.1 common.1
    @touch $@

marker: aaa.2 bbb.2
    create_2 $?
    @touch $@
```

Note that `marker` is a dummy file, and that the rules for `aaa.2` and `bbb.2` touch those targets but don't really rebuild them. It's ugly, but it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

This hack might help you out:

```
.PHONY: all

all: file1 file2
>---@if [ -f work ]; then \
>--->---touch file1 file2; \
>--->---echo "touch file1 file 2"; \
>---fi
>---rm -f work

file1:
>---touch work
file2:
>---touch work
```

This causes both files to be rebuilt if any of them need rebuilding.  You could probably use this hack, create `work1` and `work2` files instead of only `work` and use a more complicated `if` condition to rebuild just what needs rebuilding.  Works with GNU Make at least.