# Makefile $@ variable-what is it used for?

Tags: unix, gcc, makefile, gnu-make

I am new to learning make files.I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952200/how-to-build-several-targets-by-invoking-only-one-command) post.
could anyone please tell me what is `$@` variable used for inside a makefile?

Answer (score 7):

The `$@` stands for the target of the current rule. More info [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables).

Comment: And, therefore, `$@` means different things at different times while `make` is running.

Answer (score 4):

It's used to refer to the target, for example:

```
test:
        gcc -o $@ $@.c
```

Would compile program `test` from `test.c` if you ran `make test`